# How to create a button with a smaller hit area than its visual area?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to create buttons with smaller hit area to prevent misoperation in an industrial touchscreen PC program. Here is [a sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYdSu.png), 
and only [the white area should response to touch and mouse operations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dY7u.png)

I've tried to use ControlTemplate

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonToTouch" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
        <Button Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button.Content>
                <Grid Margin="8" >
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now mouse enter event works that way, but it seems that every visible pixel in the button template can trigger the click event, so i have to set the background of the border to null, and set the background somewhere out of the template.

Any suggestions? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on Border. With 8 Margin on Grid, 8px wide area will not register input.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonToTouch" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>

        <Grid Margin="8">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I added `IsHitTestVisible="False"`  on Border in my code, and it works well. Then I tried yours, it works but all animations on MouseOver and Click failed. Maybe I really need another button here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @foxsheep, standard Button template includes template triggers which change Background when IsMouseOver=true or IsPressed=true. ButtonToTouch template is missing those triggers (usually when customizing control template on has to copy them from base template).

Comment: It works great after adding `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` , that's much more direct than adding another button. Thanks again.